# Count number of pixels in different ranges for different polygons

Tags: google-earth-engine, pixel, count

I have two layers: one which contains few  seperated polygons, and one which has raster which I have uploaded (type feature collection). In addition, I have draw one for test (geometry).

My goal:

I want each polygon to get information based on its' location regard: how many pixels are in its' region that their value is lower than 0.2, between 0.2-0.4 ect.

What I have done:
I have used code that I had and tried to do this iteration for each polygon.

The result:
when running this with the GEE manual drawn polygon. calculation was done, but I got in the end imagecollection which contains this data in each feature properties. Also when I run this on my geometry (sometimes get error: geometry.geometry is not a function).

Code:

```
  var c0204 = image.gt(0.2).lt(0.4).selfMask().reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geometry,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    //maxPixels:1310361348,
    scale: 20,
  }).values().get(0);
```

This is a link to my code, let me know if the imports are unavilable.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/24f5e8f9ef310b96d632ef89454c00eb

My end goal: To have the count pixels data in table so I can know for each polygon how many pixels were found in each count category. or at least to have it as featurecollection and not as imagecollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.and()` logical function to find the intersection of two conditionals:

```js
var c0204 = image.gt(0.2).and(image.lt(0.4)).selfMask()
var c0406 = image.gt(0.4).and(image.lt(0.6)).selfMask()
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work as you use 1) different scales (I set every scale to 20m), 2) you expressions for the values in between are wrong.

If you apply this function `image.gt(0.2)` all pixel values will become 0 (for below 0.2) and 1 (for above 0.2). If you then use `.lt(0.4)` on that image, all pixels which where 1 from your previous calculations will be 1 again (because 1 is higher than 0.4, off course).

Therefore, use for example this statement:

```
  image.gt(0.2).add(image.lte(0.4)).eq(2).selfMask()
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9c51016ad79e90b0abef130b3acdfe2c)